# Apply Pivot to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sparse DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1],[1, 2], [2,1], [2,3], [3,4]], columns=['userId', 'movieId'])
```

That looks like this:

```
   userId  movieId
0       1        1
1       1        2
2       2        1
3       2        3
4       3        4
```

I want to convert this table so that it looks like this:

```
                movieId
userId      1      2    3   4
     1      1      1    0   0
     2      1      0    1   0
     3      0      0    0   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) on the df passing in the relevant cols for the index, columns and values. Here I create a boolean df as `NaN` values will be introduced where there are no values and cast the `dtype` to `int` to generate what you desire:

```
In [9]:
(df.pivot(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='movieId') > 0).astype(int)

Out[9]:
movieId  1  2  3  4
userId             
1        1  1  0  0
2        1  0  1  0
3        0  0  0  1
```

Here is what the intermediate pivot table looks like:

```
In [11]:
df.pivot(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='movieId')

Out[11]:
movieId   1   2   3   4
userId                 
1         1   2 NaN NaN
2         1 NaN   3 NaN
3       NaN NaN NaN   4
```

Comment: Perfect and pythonic

Answer (score 1):

you can add one column and then simply use [df.pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [196]: df['count'] = 1


In [198]: df.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='count', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
Out[198]:
movieId  1  2  3  4
userId
1        1  1  0  0
2        1  0  1  0
3        0  0  0  1
```

PS I have applied @jezrael's correction (added `aggfunc`) and now it will work also for the cases where there are more than one `movieId` per `userId`.

Prove:

```
In [236]: df.loc[5]=[1,1,1]

In [237]: df
Out[237]:
   userId  movieId  count
0       1        1      1
1       1        2      1
2       2        1      1
3       2        3      1
4       3        4      1
5       1        1      1

In [238]: df.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='movieId', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
Out[238]:
        count
movieId     1  2  3  4
userId
1           2  1  0  0
2           1  0  1  0
3           0  0  0  1
```

Comment: I got it now - you are absolutely right, thanks! I'll update my answer.